# All artisan commands fail to run. Including php artisan list

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting no output from php artisan.

I have checked laravel logs and php logs. I'm getting no errors it just fails silently.

I also added dumps to the artisan file and they all show on the console except when I try one after this bit of code.

```
$status = $kernel->handle( $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput, new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput );
```

I'm running L5.0 on php 5.4.41

Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: Have you tried running `composer update` and re-checking the commands?

Comment: I just did and it worked. Add your answer and I will mark it as such. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running `composer update` and re-checking the commands? It should do it :)